# Differentiate properly escaped HTML metacharacters from improperly escaped ones

Tags: scala, lift

I'm working on a replacement for a desktop Java app, a single page app written in Scala and Lift.

I have this situation where some of data in the database has properly used HTML metacharacters, such as Unicode escape sequences for accented characters in non-English names. At the same time, I have other data with improper HTML metacharacters, such as ampersands in the names or organizations.

- Good (don't escape): Universita\u0027
- Bad (needs escape): Bob & Jim

How do I determine whether or not the data needs to be fixed before I send it to the client?

There are two ways to approach this. One is a function that takes a string and returns the index of any improperly escaped HTML metacharacters (which I can fix myself). Alternately it could be a function that takes a string and returns a string with the improperly escaped metacharacters fixed, and leaves the proper ones alone.

Comment: is your application gonna receive further improper data? if not you should convert your data and work with cleansed data using http://commons.apache.org/proper/commons-lang/javadocs/api-2.6/org/apache/commons/lang/StringEscapeUtils.html#unescapeJava(java.io.Writer, java.lang.String) for instance

Comment: Converting the data isn't the problem. Knowing whether or not it needs to be converted is the problem, because sometimes the data already contains proper escape sequences that need to be sent to the client as-is.

Comment: Have you considered an HTML validator, like [JTidy](http://jtidy.sourceforge.net/) or [TagSoup](http://ccil.org/~cowan/XML/tagsoup/)? Should at least let you know if you have invalid characters and optionally clean it up.

Comment: Can I rephrase your question as "how do I find ampersands that are not part of an HTML entity"? Does this work: s/&(?!\w+;)/&amp;/ ? Or maybe \w{3,5} or something.

Comment: @Donald.McLean: I see you already came to this conclusion. Do you mind posting the answer here (people often answer their own question on SO), could have saved me some effort :)

Comment: Actually, @nafg, I am interested in finding and escaping all HTML metacharacters, not just the ampersands.

Comment: @Donald.McLean: I realized that, but I was too hasty in other respects so I'll retract.